# react - populating a form input value with a snapshot.val()

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im trying to occupy several input fields from values taken from snapshot.val() values.

Heres the value taken from the snapshot

```
 projectRef.child("subject").on("value", function(snapshot) {
        var subject = snapshot.val();
    });
```

And id like to add it to a form input in the same class.

```
<div className="col-lg-6">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <label class="control-label required">Subject</label>
                                <input value={this.state.subject} placeholder="Subject"
                                       onChange={this.handleInputChangeSubject} type="text" className="form-control"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Basically on page load id like the var subject to fill the input but id like to be able to still edit the input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just add `defaultValue={subject}` to your input box. It should do the trick.